# Arrays: Removing output int

Tags: java, arrays

i need helping writing the code for a method that will separate a array in to files one consisting of all the even int and the other consisting of all odds.

```
 public static void outputData(int[] array, int counter) throws IOException
       {
          PrinterWriter outputFile = new PrinterWriter("even.txt");
          for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
          {
             if(array[i] % 2 == 0)
             { 
                outputFile.print(array[i]);
             }

          }
```

this is what i have so far. is it right? and would i put the even on the else statement?

Comment: "*is it right?*" - SO is not a QA service :)

Comment: You're missing a `}` to end the method, but that could just be an error copying to the question. You'd put **odd** on the `else` part since the `if` is currently doing even numbers; everything else looks about right, but you'd need to run it to check.

Comment: Don't ask SO to test your questions. Try running it and testing a bunch of different variables. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

> Is what i have so far. is it right?

You can increase the code performance by replacing binary operator `%` with bitwise operator `&`, when you do the even test of `if` statement..

```
 for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
 {
    if(array[i] & 1 == 0)// & works much faster than %
     { 
        outputFile.print(array[i]);
     }
 }
```